# Why are suggested packages installed by default?

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg

I was surprised when I found that by installing `firefoxdriver`, chromium stuff will also be installed:

```
$ sudo apt install firefoxdriver 
[sudo] password for asuka: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  chromium-browser chromium-chromedriver python3-selenium
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  chromium-browser chromium-chromedriver firefoxdriver python3-selenium
0 upgraded, 4 newly installed, 0 to remove and 7 not upgraded.
Need to get 802 kB of archives.
After this operation, 1,645 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] n
Abort.
```

I dug down, finding that `firefoxdriver` depends on `python3-selenium`:

```
$ apt show firefoxdriver 
Package: firefoxdriver

...

Depends: libc6 (>= 2.4), firefox-esr | firefox, python-selenium (>= 3.14.1) | python3-selenium (>= 3.14.1)

...
```

and that `python3-selenium` recommends `chromium-driver`, which I guess is the reason why `firefoxdriver` brings in chromium packages.

```
$ apt show python3-selenium
Package: python3-selenium

...

Recommends: chromium-driver | chromedriver | phantomjs

...
```

Is my guess correct? If so, why are the recommendation packages installed by default?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Recommends` and `Suggests` are different categories.

Your output is showing `Recommends` (not `Suggests`).

Ubuntu's default setting is to install `Recommends` and to NOT install `Suggests`. Here's how you can see your current settings for yourself:

```
$ apt-config dump | grep Suggests
APT::Install-Suggests "0";         // 0 = No

$ apt-config dump | grep Recommends
APT::Install-Recommends "1";       // 1 = Yes
```

You can, of course, change the setting several ways.

The easiest way to do a one-time change is to use apt's `--no-install-recommends` flag.  Example: `sudo apt install hello --no-install-recommends`

The easiest way to do a frequent change for most folks is to change the setting using a file in `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/`

Comment: I also found `--no-install-recommends` option in `man apt-get` - it works fine!